# Install button not visible in Plugin Store

Tags: plugins, control-panel

I added my user to a user group that had every permission checked. I also looked at general.php and there was nothing about `allowUpdates`, so I added `allowUpdates = true`, but neither of these things helped.

I was not the person who installed this site, is there anything else that might cause the plugin store to lack install buttons?

[image]

Comment: My guess would have been `allowUpdates`... are you sure you're setting that in the correct environment for a multi-environment config?

Comment: @BradBell it actually had to do with the host service being used (hyperlane). It was set to git mode so it doesn't allow any changes to the filesystem through the UI.

Comment: Ahh... nice catch.  Want to add that as an official answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the Craft install is hosted at Hyperlane, they have a way of locking changes so that you have to push to the repo through git and deploy. No changes can be made to the filesystem through the admin UI.